# Is it possible to see the cursor of other emacsclients?

Tags: emacsclient, server

I'm trying to run Emacs server in order to collaborate on org files in our office.

`emacsclient` makes it quite easy to have everyone connect to the same instance of a file and we can see real time changes, but we can't see each others' cursors, making it a little awkward when someone adds something right underneath where you're typing.

Is it possible to make all clients' cursors visible to each other client?  If so, would it be possible to have other clients' cursors styled differently as to not make the whole thing very confusing?

Comment: Interesting idea.  However there's only one undo stack it seems.  When user A makes an undo, that undoes the last input, possibly made of user B.  How do you deal with that?

Comment: I was not aware that there is only a single undo stack.  This would greatly complicate things.  I'm struggling to find a way to collaborate on org files that doesn't come up with a dead end though...

Comment: https://github.com/zk-phi/togetherly/ seems to display the other cursors.

Comment: I have come across togetherly before, but it seems like it's not really supported anymore.  Might still be the best place to start though.